# Using jQuery to include/require a different php file if window height > 1000?

Tags: jquery, include, window, height

How can you use jQuery to include/require a different php file if `window height > 1000`?

```
if window height > 1000

    <?php require('a.php'); ?>

else

    <?php require('b.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect the width and height in javascript and then redirect the page to your actual page.

```
location.href="myRealPage.php?height="+clientheight;
```

Then you can use these variables on the server to decide which page to load.

```
if($_GET["height"]>1000)
{
   require("a.php")?
}
else
{
   require("b.php")?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't `require` like `php` in JavaScript/jQuery. Instead of that you can use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load). It will load an script using AJAX.

For example:

```
if( $(window).height() > 1000 ) {
  $('#result').load('a.php', function() {
      alert('a.php load was performed.');
  });
} else {
  $('#result').load('b.php', function() {
      alert('b.php load was performed.');
  });
}
```

But If you want to reload page then you need `window.location` ie.

```
window.location = "some_url";
```